# Gatling out of memory,

Tags: jvm, gatling

I am running an endurance test that I originally planed for a duration of five days.
However, after around 13.5 hours the test crashes with OOM after one of my tested application NGINX crashed and I started getting loads of timeouts:

```
22:33:59  > i.g.h.c.i.RequestTimeoutException: Request timeout to api.rnd.  22028 (32.23%)
22:33:59  .com/54.191.252.45:443 after 60000 ms
22:33:59  > i.g.h.c.i.RequestTimeoutException: Request timeout to api.rnd.  21957 (32.12%)
22:33:59  .com/34.210.130.50:443 after 60000 ms
22:33:59  > i.g.h.c.i.RequestTimeoutException: Request timeout to api.rnd.  21912 (32.06%)
22:33:59  .com/100.20.123.44:443 after 60000 ms
```

Note that during peaks in my tests I might have around 8K concurrent users

The test is running through Jenkins on a c5.xlarge with the following memory JVM parameters:

```
-Xms2g -Xmx3g
```

And here is the exception I got:

```
22:33:59  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
22:33:59  20:33:55.543 [gatling-http-1-3][WARN ][DefaultPromise.java:580] i.n.u.c.DefaultPromise - An exception was thrown by io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient$$Lambda$558/0x000000084054a840.operationComplete()
22:33:59  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
22:33:59    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:305)
22:33:59    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:157)
22:33:59    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:150)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.openNewChannelRec(DefaultHttpClient.java:629)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.openNewChannel(DefaultHttpClient.java:603)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.sendTxWithNewChannel(DefaultHttpClient.java:493)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.lambda$sendTx$2(DefaultHttpClient.java:378)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient$$Lambda$558/0x000000084054a840.operationComplete(Unknown Source)
22:33:59    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
22:33:59    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
22:33:59    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
22:33:59    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:183)
22:33:59    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:35)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.sendTx(DefaultHttpClient.java:360)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.sendRequest(DefaultHttpClient.java:263)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.engine.HttpEngine.executeRequest(HttpEngine.scala:149)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.engine.tx.HttpTxExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(HttpTxExecutor.scala:142)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.engine.tx.HttpTxExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(HttpTxExecutor.scala:126)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.engine.tx.HttpTxExecutor$$Lambda$686/0x0000000840623840.apply(Unknown Source)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.engine.tx.HttpTxExecutor.executeWithCache(HttpTxExecutor.scala:53)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.engine.tx.HttpTxExecutor.execute(HttpTxExecutor.scala:126)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.engine.tx.HttpTxExecutor.execute(HttpTxExecutor.scala:120)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.action.HttpRequestAction.$anonfun$sendRequest$1(HttpRequestAction.scala:67)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.action.HttpRequestAction.$anonfun$sendRequest$1$adapted(HttpRequestAction.scala:59)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.action.HttpRequestAction$$Lambda$685/0x0000000840623040.apply(Unknown Source)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.commons.validation.Success.map(Validation.scala:45)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.http.action.HttpRequestAction.sendRequest(HttpRequestAction.scala:59)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.core.action.RequestAction.$anonfun$execute$1(Action.scala:100)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.core.action.RequestAction$$Lambda$660/0x0000000840609040.apply(Unknown Source)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.commons.validation.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:46)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.core.action.RequestAction.execute(Action.scala:97)
22:33:59    at io.gatling.core.action.RequestAction.execute$(Action.scala:96)
22:33:59  20:33:55.546 [gatling-http-1-6][ERROR][HttpAppHandler.java:230] i.g.h.c.i.HttpAppHandler - Fatal error
22:33:59  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Could be that the 60 seconds timeout is the cause? It's a default parameter that I didn't change.

Comment: what sort of things are you storing in the session? Sometimes I've had issues in my scripts where I've liberally used .findAll on responses that have thousands upon thousands of responses and filled my session with massive amounts of data. Replicate this sort of thing across 8k users and you can soon get into trouble. The solution is to manually remove that data from the session once you're done with it.

Comment: 8K concurrent users each with their own session? depending on what you store in that session, you simply might not have enough memory. as simple as that. otherwise, you could enable GC logging and figure out what is going on, but unless you have some basic knowledge about GC, this is not going to be enjoyable.

Comment: Might I suggest attaching to the process in question with visualvm. It can give you a good idea of what is using your memory.